# Binding through variable declaration in model class doesn't work, but calling a bind function does work

Tags: cakephp

I have the following model

```
class Comment extends AppModel {
    var $useTable = "comments";
    var $recursive = 1;

    var $belongsTo = array(
                    'User' => array(
                        'className' => 'User',
                        'foreignKey'    => 'userID'

                    )
                );

    function bindCommentsToUser() {

        $this->bindModel(
            array('belongsTo' => array(
                    'User' => array(
                        'className' => 'User',
                        'foreignKey'    => 'userID'

                    )
                )
            )
        ); 
    }
```

The belongsTo variable at the top does absolutely nothing, I just cannot get it to work. 
To confirm that the binding exists, I created the lower function to do dynamic binding which works perfectly. There appears to be no difference between the two. Is there some mistake that I am making or is there some setting somewhere else that has to be set?

Comment: I'm guessing that Cake does the underscore thingy with the userID in one, but not the other.  If you can, I'd recommend sticking with cake's conventions -- use user_id rather than userID.  Cake does funny stuff with capitalization sometimes.

Comment: Can you include the additional code you used to verify that one variation works and the other doesn't? Understanding the test being applied may help determine why the test is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be the same in both cases. You may want to create a ticket at http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com. If possible change 'userID' to 'user_id' as recommended Travis Lleu. That will work for sure.

Comment: chaning the database columns to _id worked. Will open a ticket when I get a chance