# CakePHP - hasMany not fetching?

Tags: php, cakephp

Maybe I am just having a slow day, but for the life of me I can't figure out why this is happening. I haven't done CakePHP in a while and I am trying to use the 1.3 version, but this doesn't seem to be working...

I have two models:

#### area.php

```
<?php
class Area extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Area';
    var $useTable = 'OR_AREA';
    var $primaryKey = 'A_ID';

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Building' => array(
            'className' => 'Building',
            'foreignKey' => 'FK_B_ID',
        ),
        'Facility' => array(
            'className' => 'Facility',
            'foreignKey' => 'FK_F_ID',
        ),
        'System' => array(
            'className' => 'System',
            'foreignKey' => 'FK_S_ID',
        )
    );
}
?>
```

#### building.php

```
<?php
class Building extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Building';
    var $useTable = 'OR_BLDG';
    var $primaryKey = 'B_ID';

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Area' => array(
            'className' => 'Area',
            'foreignKey' => 'FK_B_ID',
        )                    
    );
}
?>
```

`OR_AREA` has a column titled `FK_B_ID` that refers to the `B_ID`.

If I run something like:

```
$this->Building->find('all', array('recursive' => 2));
```

I get empty `[Area]` arrays for all the Buildings even though there are plenty of Areas in the `OR_AREA` table that are associated to buildings. Not only that, the Query Table doesn't even show CakePHP attempted to find anything but all the records in `OR_BLDG`. All the more puzzling, if I do:

```
$this->Area->find('all');
```

I get all the Areas and the `[Building]` arrays are populated when appropriate.

What am I missing?

### Edit:

The relevant parts of my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDB_ADMIN.OR_AREA
(
  A_ID            NUMBER(8),
  NAME            VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)            NOT NULL,
  FK_F_ID         NUMBER(8),
  FK_S_ID         NUMBER(8),
  FK_B_ID         NUMBER(8)
)

CREATE TABLE ORDB_ADMIN.OR_BLDG
(
  B_ID           NUMBER(8),
  BLDG           VARCHAR2(90 BYTE)              NOT NULL
)
```

I do feel it is worthwhile to mention that I am using **Oracle** and I found [a ticket](https://dev.cakephp.org/ticket/5939) that seems to describe what is happening to me but it was closed 18 months ago and no real details were provided on what was the problem/what was done to correct it.

I also found a comment in the "hasMany" section of the 1.2 CakePHP Book that reads:

> If your hasMany association doesn't return any records, check if the column types of the primary key and the foreignKey are the same. If one is int and the other is char, you won't get any records from the association (and no warnings).

But, as you can see above, the key columns are NUMBERs on both ends (which is what CakePHP wants them to be for Oracle as well)

Comment: Just checking: depending on how you define "area", your associations may be backwards? What does your db schema look like?

Comment: @deceze: I've developed a lot of CakePHP apps in the past (granted, most were in 1.1) and I really think I got the whole hasMany/belongsTo thing down. I updated the question with the schema in case I am crazy, though.

Comment: As I said, just checking. You said you might have a slow day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out why this is happening. Although I defined my columns all uppercase in Oracle CakePHP brings them over lowercased and is unable to find them when you define your custom columns as uppercase. So changing all of my $primaryKey and foreignKey definitions to lowercase fixed my issue.

I opened a [ticket](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/812-hasmany-with-a-custom-primary-key-and-a-custom-foreignkey-not-fetched-properly-in-oracle) on this issue before finding out the reason, but I am not sure there's much to be done other than perhaps making a note in the Book so that someone doesn't waste a few days on this again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, whether this is correct or not but you have what looks like to me incorrect foreignKeys Area Model... is that the case?

Comment: How are they wrong? When defining belongsTo the documentation defines 'foreignKey' as "foreignKey: the name of the foreign key found in the current model." - so if Area belongsTo Building and the column in Area that points to Building is FK_B_ID then that is what you put in the belongsTo declaration... no?

Answer (score 0):

It seems for me that there is something wrong with belogsTo associations in cakephp 1.3. I think it will everything ok if you change you foreign keys to `area_id` and `building_id`. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828930/binding-through-variable-declaration-in-model-class-doesnt-work-but-calling-a-b/2830369#2830369) post. Another person had the similar problem and that solution worked for him.

Comment: The belongsTo end of my association works fine, it's the hasMany that isn't working. This is, unfortunately, an application that already exists and I am porting over to CakePHP so I cannot change the column name. I will make a few empty tables to see if that is the problem, though.

Comment: By the way, have you tried to do the same thing in Cakephp 1.2? I have not heard about any issues with foreign keys there. If you cannot change the database maybe that would be a good solution for you (to use Cakephp 1.2)?

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be some issues when dealing with custom foreign keys. I had a similar issue to yours. At first I tried using dynamic bind functions and they worked most of the time.

However, recently I went back and changed everything to xxx_id (cakephp does a lot of weird stuff with underbars so xxxx should not contain any underbars) and all the relationships just started working perfectly.

Therefore, I would suggest making all foreign keys xxxx_id and see if that clears up your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this is a legacy application I am porting to CakePHP so I cannot rename the columns. I might just have to roll up my sleeves and find the error inside the oracle db driver but I would *really* like to avoid that.